# Is it possible to "punch" textured text from an image, with GD or similar?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, gd, textures, text-rendering

is it also possible to "punch" text from an image, so that I get a text-image with part of an image as texture, from the offset where I "punched"?

I know I can write text on an image with GD. I've read about being able to texture text with a smaller image to tile-fill text, but that's not what I am looking for.. Compare the below example, if my question still haven't made sense.

Example (via http://www.photoshopessentials.com/images/type/effects/texture-text/photoshop-textured-text.gif):
[image: textured text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are instructions for compositing.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#mask

You need

1. A black image (e.g. black-bg.png)
2. The ripple image (e.g. ripple-overlay.png)
3. The text image, with the text white on black (e.g. text-mask.png)

All three should be the same size.  Then,

```
composite black-bg.png ripple-overlay.png text-mask.png final.png
```

for #3, the mask can actually be grayscale, with the gray level controlling how much of each image is used.

- Black -- use the pixel from the background
- White -- use the pixel from the overlay image
- Gray -- mix them based on the gray level (you might want this for anti-aliasing around the letters)

Comment: Thanks for this "workaround" [ ;) which might quite probably the only way to achieve what I try to do]. Can you think of another way to get the same result, maybe setting the texture as a background for text, with a (possibly negative on the x/y-axis) offset value? Is GD able to munge bg imagery for text?? ---Thanks again for your solution!

Comment: sorry, this is the only way I can think of doing this.